# How to get values from Textarea while preserving newlines with PHP?

Tags: php

I have a very simple form with a textarea.

I can get the textarea's value with PHP by:

```
<?php $val = $_POST['txt']; ?>
```

My question is, that, how could I preserve the newline separators when I'm processing the text?

I intend to send a Plain text email, NOT a HTML email, this is why I need PHP to send the email in the exact same format, which the user types in the textarea.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `nl2br`? (http://www.php.net/nl2br)

```
echo nl2br($val);
```

Comment: He doesn't want a HTML email, ONLY plain text, http://uk3.php.net/nl2br converts `\n` etc to `<br />`

Answer (score 0):

**Answer found:**

If you are planning to send Plain text email messages, you should only use the raw Textarea data and paste it as the email's body.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything... Because you already have the new lines when you get the data from your `textarea`... Just make sure to use double quotes `"` and not single `'` for new lines `\n`.

```
echo '\n'; // this will output these two characters: \n
echo "\n"; // this will output a new line
```